# Belkin Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock dual Dell U2515H setup

Tags: display, dock

I have a similar question as this [one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181934/belkin-thunderbolt-2-express-dock-hd-dual-monitor-setup), except I have specific hardware that I want to connect.

I have a MacBook Pro 15" Retina Mid-2014 and a [Belkin Thunderbolt 2 Express dock](http://www.belkin.com/uk/p/P-F4U085/).
Now I want two [Dell U2515H](http://www1.la.dell.com/vc/en/corp/peripherals/dell-u2515h-monitor/pd.aspx?refid=dell-u2515h-monitor&s=corp) monitors and connect them to the Belkin Dock. Is this possible and what cables do I need?

If it is not possible, I need to fallback to connect just one U2515H to the dock and one to the MacBook, would that be possible?

Comment: This is not a duplicate because the other question is general, mine is about specific hardware!

Comment: Fair enough, I've removed my comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless one of the displays is a Thunderbolt display, you cannot connect two displays to a Belkin Thunderbolt Dock (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181934/belkin-thunderbolt-2-express-dock-hd-dual-monitor-setup)).

As neither of your displays is using Thunderbolt, you have two options:

1. Connect one display to the dock and one to the MacBook Pro. One end of the cable (going into the dock or MacBook Pro) could be HDMI or Mini DisplayPort and the other end would need to be one of the monitor's connections (see below).
2. Connect both displays to the MacBook Pro. One end of the cable (going into the MacBook Pro) could be HDMI or Mini DisplayPort and the other end would need to be one of the monitor's connections (see below)

The Dell U2515s have a full selection of connectors - Display Port, Mini DisplayPort, HDMI, etc. so you really can choose which suits you best. It's probably easiest to buy a pair of Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cables (which will support both scenarios I described above).

See Apple document [HT204154](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204154) for a general discussion of Thunderbolt ports and displays.